# Convert seconds to days, hours, minutes in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, type-conversion

i'm having trouble in converting seconds in Bigquery, is there any function to convert seconds to hour:minute:second format in Bigquery? i already tried the `TIMESTAMP_SECONDS()` function but it also returns some date and i can't use it if the hour more than 23.
for example:

second= 100000

result= 27:46:40

or maybe as 1 day 3 hour 46 minute 40 second

and i also want it in timestamp datatype so i can order it ascending or descending.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select seconds, 
  regexp_replace(
    cast(time(ts) as string), 
    r'^\d\d', 
    cast(extract(hour from time(ts)) + 24 * unix_date(date(ts)) as string)
  ) as option1, 
  format(
    '%i day %i hour %i minute %i second', 
    unix_date(date(ts)), 
    extract(hour from time(ts)), 
    extract(minute from time(ts)), 
    extract(second from time(ts))
  ) as option2
from `project.dataset.table`, 
unnest([timestamp_seconds(seconds)]) ts
```

if to apply to sample data from your question as in

```
with `project.dataset.table` AS (
  select 100000 seconds union all
  select 200000 union all
  select 300000
)
```

the output is

[image]

Comment: wow! thankyou so much! but it can't be order by asc or desc since it converts to string, can it?

Comment: you still need to use your original filed (in this case `seconds`) to do whatever ordering you need. obviously the output as it is cannot be used for ordering  - unless you will normalize it by let's say having all components two digits and first component (hours in option1 and days in option2) let's say of 4 digits - depends on expected numbers

Answer (score 2):

With recently introduced INTERVAL data type and respective functions - such conversion becomes much easier

```
select seconds, 
  make_interval(second => seconds) result,
  justify_interval(make_interval(second => seconds)) normalized_result
from `project.dataset.table`
```

with output like

[image]