# BigQuery Convert number of seconds into time format

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to convert average total of seconds into time format
PARSE_TIME( '%T',
CAST(ROUND( IEEE_DIVIDE(SUM( totals.timeOnSite ), SUM(totals.visits)),0) AS STRING )) AS AvgSessionDuration,

code is valid, but it's giving me this error:
Failed to parse input string "245"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below approach

```
time(timestamp_seconds(number_of_seconds_int64)) AS AvgSessionDuration
```

instead of `PARSE_TIME( '%T', CAST(ROUND( IEEE_DIVIDE(SUM( totals.timeOnSite ), SUM(totals.visits)),0) AS STRING )) AS AvgSessionDuration`

Comment: I believe this works fine for seconds less than 86400 (1 day).  86399 would be `23:59:59`, but 86400 is `00:00:00`.  If you expect durations of 1 day or longer, maybe this solution works better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64517385/1549523