# Why are we using two mods for timestamp_diff of seconds in time

Tags: sql, time, google-bigquery, modulo, timestampdiff

As a part of a course, I have been trying to analyze a dataset of fitness device which has timestamps. I'm trying to take a difference of time in order to calculate no. of hours a user is sleeping. And for that I came across this code -

```
SELECT
   Id,
   TIME( TIMESTAMP_DIFF(MAX(date),MIN(date),HOUR),
     MOD(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(MAX(date),MIN(date),MINUTE),60),
     MOD(MOD(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(MAX(date),MIN(date),SECOND),3600),60) )AS time_sleeping
```

My question is why are we using "MOD" two times in the last line of the query when seconds can be converted from hours by only dividing by 3600?
PS :- I'm new to SQL so ignore my silly question, if in case it is :)Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are right, a the two `mod` can be combinded. Please check yourself:

```sql
SELECT
  x,
  MOD(MOD(x,60),3600) a,
  MOD(x,60) b
FROM
  UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(-4000,4000)) x
order by abs(a-b) desc
```

For a better time conversion see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68718496/bigquery-convert-number-of-seconds-into-time-format):

```sql
SELECT
  TIME(
    TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(
#     MOD( 
       TIMESTAMP_DIFF(
         TIMESTAMP("2022-09-02 09:30:11"),
         TIMESTAMP("2022-09-01 23:00:02"),
         second
         )
#        ,3600*24      )
    )
  )
```