# How to convert SQL Bigquery results from seconds to HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql, time, google-bigquery, aggregate

I have a column that is technically HH:MM:SS, but is seen as a string because of an error. I've been able to convert the table to time in my queries with PARSE_TIME, but BigQuery won't let me Average them in that format.
I had to change the column to seconds in order for it to work, but I'm not sure how to now get the results to show in HH:MM:SS format.

Is there a way to add to my query to convert the seconds to the format I need after it's finished averaging?

Query:

```
SELECT day_of_week, member_casual, AVG(TIME_DIFF(SAFE.PARSE_TIME('%T', ride_length), TIME '00:00:00', SECOND))ride_length_seconds,
FROM `circular-nova-330422.trip_data_Cyclist.trip_data-12mths`
GROUP BY day_of_week, member_casual;
```

Results:

1887.7346433179848

1649.2725911597283

1477.5820550816654

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64517385/11520306) work for you?

Comment: No, the first answer doesn't work and  I'm unable to change my column to INT for the second answer.